# Ajax error calling web method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I am trying to set the date in a Bootstrap datetime picker based on drop down list selection change. I am using a web method (C#) to return "start date" given a "certificate ID".

I tried using "text" data type instead of "json" but keep getting "Cannot convert object of type System.String to type System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary"

I searched for this error type and could not find something that would resolve this issue.

```
$("#ddlCertificate").change(function () {
    ....
    debugger
    setStartDate($("#ddlCertificate").val());
});

function setStartDate(certItemID) {
    var param = JSON.stringify(certItemID, null, 2);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "../services/easg.asmx/GetCertItemStartDate",
        cache: false,
        data: param,
    }).done(function (result) {debugger
        $("#tbStartDate").val(result.d);
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {debugger
        alert(textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
    });
}
```

Web Method:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

public string GetCertItemStartDate(string certID)
{
    int iCertItemID = int.Parse(certID);
    DateTime dtStartDate = CertItem.GetCertItemStartDate(iCertItemID);
    string JSONresult;
    JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtStartDate);
    return JSONresult;
}
```

Comment: `I tried using "text" data type instead of "json"` Why?

Comment: in one post I read if I want to receive one item back as string I had to set data type to "text". It didn't work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the way the parameter was being passed. In ajax call, I had:

```
data: param,
```

and had to change it to:

```
$("#ddlCertificate").change(function () {
    ....
    var certID = "{ 'certID': '" + $('#ddlCertificate').val() + "'}";
    setStartDate(certID);
});

function setStartDate(certItemID) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "../services/easg.asmx/GetCertItemStartDate",
        cache: false,
        data: certItemID,
    }).done(function (result) {
        var startDate = JSON.parse(result.d);
        setStartDate(new Date(startDate));
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
    });
}
```